# knnsearch(X,Y) not returning an element of X

Tags: matlab

I am trying to implement a k-nearest neighbors function in some of my code. I am running into a rather strange issue that I cannot understand. Let

```
X=[1,4,51,3,2,4,6]' % a column vector
knnsearch(X,8) %returns 7!
```

I have tested this out and usually knnsearch(X,Y) will return for a given element in Y, the nearest neighbor *in X*. But of course '7' is not an element in X at all, but knnsearch(X,8) is returning 7. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns the **index** and **not the element** itself.

```
>> X = [1, 12, 33, 14]';
>> nn = knnsearch(X, 8);
>> X(nn) %Will print 12
```

`nn` holds the index (in this case it is `2`).

So `X(nn)` will give you `12`, which is the expected answer.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't parse the code description properly and used poor examples to test my understanding.

Comment: It happened to me once with this function :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exhaustivesearcher.knnsearch.html):

```
IDX = knnsearch(NS,Y)

[...]

IDX is a column vector with ny rows, where ny is the number of rows in Y. 
Each row in IDX contains the index of observation in NS.X which has the 
smallest distance to the corresponding observation in Y.
```

`knnsearch` doesn't return the nearest neighbour, it return the *index* of the nearest neighbour.  In your example, `6` is the closest element to `8`, and it's at index `7`, so you get `7`.